# How to bring floating action button outside of the Android app?

Tags: java, android, translation

I want to create an android app that can translate any text on the screen of the user. It should work throughout the Android Phone on all apps. I want to bring a floating action button outside the app and make it run as a visible, moveable, and clickable background services.
The floating button will take the copied text and then translate it using google translate API.

Please help me, I need some guidance and resource.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Please check below Java and XML file for floating action button

**JAVA**

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MovableFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private final static float CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE = 10; // Often, there will be a slight, unintentional, drag when the user taps the FAB, so we need to account for this.

    private float downRawX, downRawY;
    private float dX, dY;

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MovableFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();

        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            downRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            downRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();
            dX = view.getX() - downRawX;
            dY = view.getY() - downRawY;

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

            int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = view.getHeight();

            View viewParent = (View)view.getParent();
            int parentWidth = viewParent.getWidth();
            int parentHeight = viewParent.getHeight();

            float newX = motionEvent.getRawX() + dX;
            newX = Math.max(layoutParams.leftMargin, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the left hand side of the parent
            newX = Math.min(parentWidth - viewWidth - layoutParams.rightMargin, newX); // Don't allow the FAB past the right hand side of the parent

            float newY = motionEvent.getRawY() + dY;
            newY = Math.max(layoutParams.topMargin, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the top of the parent
            newY = Math.min(parentHeight - viewHeight - layoutParams.bottomMargin, newY); // Don't allow the FAB past the bottom of the parent

            view.animate()
                    .x(newX)
                    .y(newY)
                    .setDuration(0)
                    .start();

            return true; // Consumed

        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            float upRawX = motionEvent.getRawX();
            float upRawY = motionEvent.getRawY();

            float upDX = upRawX - downRawX;
            float upDY = upRawY - downRawY;

            if (Math.abs(upDX) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE && Math.abs(upDY) < CLICK_DRAG_TOLERANCE) { // A click
                return performClick();
            }
            else { // A drag
                return true; // Consumed
            }

        }
        else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<com.example.MovableFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnFab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_white_24dp"/>
```

Comment: how this code work outside the app?